# Как вставлять картинки в таблицу с помощью БД?

Tags: html, php, css, mysql

Я просто знаю, как текст вставлять. А картинки как?

Comment: Как BLOB, конечно. А причём тут html и css?

Comment: не стоит вставлять картинку в базу. если, конечно нет такой острой необходимости в контексте реализации приложения. вместо этого лучше сохранять в базе ссылки на изображения, а сами картинки складывать в папочку.

Comment: я тоже подумал об этом. А как выявить ссылку в виде картинки в таблице? Там же сама ссылка будет выявлена. Разве нет? @Heleg

Comment: > А как выявить ссылку в виде картинки в таблице? Там же сама ссылка будет выявлена

что означает это словоблудие?

Comment: т.е в виде текста -_-

Comment: я не понимат, оч ем ты щас сказал, но осмелюсь предположить, что ты имел ввиду, как получить изображение по ссылке. всё очень просто! при загрузке сохраняешь имя картинки (или генерируешь его). как правильно аплодить файлы есть куча статей. затем это имя просто сохраняешь в базе. выходит, у нас хранится только имя картинки. затем ты извлекаешь имя из базы и просто подставляешь в код
    
    <img src="path/to/image/dir/<?php echo $image_name ?>">

грубо говоря, зная имя картинки и имя папки, где она хранится, получить саму картинку проще простого. думаю, не стоит тут опускаться до прямого код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала нам нужно создать таблицу в **MySQL**. Назовем ее *img*, а потом вставим в нее такие столбики:

```
id
img
text
```

в img вставим путь к картинке,

**Например:** */image/img.jpg*

И на конец простым **php** кодом выводим все картинки в цикле:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

  echo "Картинка: <img src='".$row['img']."'><br />
        ID картинки: ".$row['id']."<br />
        Описание: ".$row['text']."<br />";

}
```

*Ну вот так, как то :)*

Comment: хотелось бы чтоб все так отвечали! Спасибо!))

Comment: @navi1893, Всегда пожалуйста, обращайтесь, помогу чем смогу :)

Comment: не стоит прописывать полный путь к изображению. это плохо в плане универсальности. что будешь делать, если нужно будет поменять имя папки с изображениями? переименовывать все поля таблицы бд?

Comment: @Heleg, я показал наглядно, а автор вопроса я уверен, что догадался как нужно сделать :)А если и даже нужно нужно будет удалить путь к картинке можно написать простой код на **php** с запросом **mysql_query('UPDATE ..')** ;)

Comment: да, я понимаю, просто предостерег